# Display image with quality - bitmap size exceeds VM budget Error

Tags: android, image, bitmap, out-of-memory

I need to create a gallery type application. Where i need display many image and give the zooming and sliding effects.
Now I am using `android.widget.Gallery` and setting the image to `imageview` in the `getview` of my gallery `Adapter` class (`extends BaseAdapter`). Me set image using bitmap, which is set by the following code

```
Bitmap  mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePathArray.get(position));
imageview.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
```

It works fine at first, but after moving to third or fourth image the application crash with the following error

```
  ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12184):  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12184):  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

at the decodeFile statement.

When i searched for `bitmap size exceeds VM budget`, i got a lot of solutions like [android-strange-out-of-memory-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue). But all solutions are reducing the image quality.
**What is the best method to display image in good quality and with less memory, that will not cause `bitmap size exceeds VM budget`?**
Any suggestion?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution you have is to load your bitmap at a smaller size (BitmapFactory.Options lets you resample a bitmap at load time), or try to recycle other large bitmaps you may have loaded and that you don't need anymore.

Comment: Thanks Romain Guy for your answer. can you please give me some link how to do this recycle bitmap?